# To check whether series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have following series.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\arctan (n)}{n^{1.2}}\right)$$

I think to determine whether it is convergent or divergent, comparison test might get useful but I don't know the relation of $\arctan (n)$ with $n$. Any hint?

Comment: $\arctan(n)$ is bounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we've $\left \vert \arctan (n)\right \vert <\dfrac{\pi}{2}  $ ,

$$\left \vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\arctan (n)}{n^{1.2}}\right) \right \vert < \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{1.2}}\right) = \frac {\pi}{2} \zeta (1.2) <\infty$$

[$\zeta (s)$ (Riemann Zeta function)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function?wprov=sfla1)

$(\zeta (s)$ converges for each $s >1)$

Comment: and  by p-test we can say it is convergent.

Comment: @omkarGirkar Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The integral test could be used as well I believe, though not as elegant as this argument...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|\arctan(x)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is very useful to know to what $\arctan(n) $ looks like. A hint could be that $\arctan(n) \to \frac \pi 2$. Now make some argumentation  to use the comparison test.

Let me know if this hint is not enough.